# How to add ref to dynamically added element using document.createelement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to reactjs and i have a goal to achieve movable multiple elements. I have tried it one and multiple I am successful in it but when it comes to dynamically created elements using document.createelement I am haveing problem with assigning dynamic ref to it. I have tried react.createelement but other components are affected with it.

Here is my code

```
    const container = document.createElement('span');

    container.id = spanId;
    container.className = 'videocontainer';
    
    
    //container.handleRef = ref;
    container.setAttribute('ref','{ref => {this.handleref = ref;}}');
  // container.ref = '{ref => {this.handleref = ref;}}';
    container.onMouseDown='{this.initialiseDrag}';

    //console.log(container.ref);



    container.innerHTML = `
        <div class = 'videocontainer__background'></div>
        <div class = 'videocontainer__toptoolbar'></div>
        <div class = 'videocontainer__toolbar'></div>
        <div class = 'videocontainer__hoverOverlay'></div>
        <div class = 'displayNameContainer'></div>
        <div class = 'avatar-container'></div>
        <div class ='presence-label-container'></div>
        <span class = 'remotevideomenu'></span>`;

    const remoteVideosContainer
        = document.getElementById('filmstripRemoteVideosContainer');
    const localVideoContainer
        = document.getElementById('localVideoTileViewContainer');

   remoteVideosContainer.insertBefore(container, localVideoContainer);
```

How to add ref to these dynamically created elements. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this part of a larger React app? This is not how you create or render React components. To provide any helpful information we need more detail. Why are you creating the span element like that instead of writing a React component? Where is the spanId coming from? What is the parent component?

Comment: Yes, It's a larger react app. JItsi video conferencing open-source application. Yes, I know but when I started changing the code... it throws lot of errors.. I was asking is there any way to attach the ref like this.

Comment: how did you solve it?